# compare values with values in a table

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

what i want is for cell C10 to contain the value of column 5 in my table, only if column 1 and 2 both match the date and name in cells a1 and b1

ive tried to achieve this with a formula but i can only get it to compare 2 things, formula below.

i can get it to match the date in the sheet with the date in the table, then give me column 5's value for that matching row, but i cant get it to acknowledge the name as well so cell C10 is getting a note for someone else because the dates match despite the names not matching.

i have also included a mockup up with 4 examples of what should be happening.

I think it is possible it can be done by formula, i found something when i was trying to google this problem but i dont have a clue what its talking about and i feel like it would be really easy with vba

https://exceljet.net/formula/index-and-match-with-multiple-criteria

```
=INDEX(TblNotes[#All],MATCH(Date,TblNotes[[#All],[Date]],0),5)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you may want to use Database formulas

1. insert a row above the first one
2. write "Date" and "Name" in cells A1 and B1 respectively
3. place the following formula in C10

   ```
   =DGET(TblNotes[#All],"Comment",A1:B2)
   ```

Comment: hey thanks for giving this a go, i tried what you said and i just get  #Value!

Comment: wowwwww after some fiddling about and turning a1:b1 into a table i got it working you are an absolute genious!!! i knew it could be done i never even heard of DGET!!. now how do i make it show as blank when there is no match instead of #Value!

Comment: =IFERROR(DGET(TblNotes[#All],5,Table6[#All]),"") got it

Comment: For some reason that was causing some intense flickering so i started again and worked step by step, and realised you said A1:B2 hehe i thought you said A1:B1, so now it works without turning it into a table and no more flickering, you are the boss!

Comment: never know this formula before it is amazing!!